# Angular / Java Script - reference "class" properties before object is instantiated?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a c# background and I'm starting to explore Angular JS.  And I am basing my factory classes/objects on this article: https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/2e6a067c73bc

so I have 2 factory classes, but I would like to reference an instance of one factory inside the other factory.  However, since java script is not a typed language, the properties and methods of one factory are not available inside the other factory at "compile" time.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Frinkahedron/PxdSP/1337/
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

```
myApp.factory('grid', function () {

// Constructor, with parameters
function grid(sizeX, sizeY, gridName) {
    //public properties
    this.cells = new Array();
    this.name = gridName;

    //load cells
    var numCells = sizeX * sizeY;
    for (var i = 0; i < numCells; i++) {
        this.cells.push(i);
    }
}

//Return the constructor function
return grid;
});

myApp.factory('game', ['grid', function (_grid_) {
//private reference for the grid factory
var grid = _grid_;

function game(){
    //do some setup with grid reference
    this.gridName = "Grid : " + grid.gridName;
};

game.prototype.isWinner = function () {
    //iterate cells to see if game has been won  

    //this loop doesn't cause "compile" errors
    for (var c in grid.cells){
        //do something with each cell in the grid
    }

    //this loop doesn't work due to grid.cells.length 
    //because there is no length property of undefined 
    //uncomment to see it blow up
    //for(var i=0; i< grid.cells.length;i++){}
    return true;
};

return game;
}]);


function MyCtrl($scope, grid, game) {
var g = new grid(3, 3, "Test Grid");

$scope.myLength = g.cells.length;
$scope.myGridName = g.name;
//how to pass the grid reference to the game?
//if i pass the grid in the constructor of the game, 
//it still doesn't work because javascript doesn't have types
//and the grid.cells (and other grid property references) are
//problematic
var a = new game();
$scope.myGameName = a.gridName;
$scope.myWinner = a.isWinner();
}
```

The Grid factory is working as expected, but I cannot figure out how to reference an instance of the grid in the Game factory.  I've tried passing a grid "object" into the Game constructor, but since java script is not a typed language, the grid properties / methods are undefined in the Game factory.

Answer (score 0):

In angular a factory is supposed to return an object. You return a function.

Its seems you want a provider to be able to configure your grid instead of a factory.

Example (untested):

```
myApp.provider('grid', function () {
  'use strict';

  var x, y, name;

  var Grid = function () {
    // Grid instance has access to x, y and name
  };

  this.setX = function (newx) {
    x = newx;
  };

  this.sety = function (newy) {
    y = newy;
  };

  this.setname = function (n) {
    name = n;
  };

  this.$get = function () {
    return new Grid();
  };

});
```

With this provider you can:

```
myApp.configure(['gridProvider',
  function (gridProvider) {
    'use strict';

    gridProvider.setx(100);
    gridProvider.sety(100);
    gridProvider.setname('name');

  }
]);

myApp.controller('myCtrl',
 ['grid', '$scope',
  function (grid, $scope) {
    'use strict';

     // grid is now an instance of 'Grid'
  }
 ]);
```

EDIT

```
myApp.factory('Grid', function () {
  'use strict';

  function Grid(sizeX, sizeY, gridName) {
    var
    i, numCells = sizeX * sizeY;

    this.cells = [];
    this.name = gridName;

    for (i = 0; i < numCells; i++) {
      this.cells.push(i);
    }
  }

  return Grid;
});

myApp.factory('Game', function () {
  'use strict';

   function Game(grid){
     this.gridName = "Grid : " + grid.name;
   };

   Game.prototype = {
     isWinner: function () {
       var i, l;
       for (i = 0, l = grid.cells.length; i < l; i++) {
         //do something with each cell in the grid
       }
       return true;
     }
   };

   return Game;
});


myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'Grid', 'Game',
function ($scope, Grid, Game) {
  'use strict';
  var
  grid = new Grid(3, 3, "Test Grid"),
  game = new Game(grid);

  $scope.myLength = grid.cells.length;
  $scope.myGridName = grid.name;
  $scope.myGameName = game.gridName;
  $scope.myWinner = game.isWinner();
}]);
```

Comment: I can already get an instance of the grid in the controller.  My problem is that I can't reference the instance of the grid in the Game factory.  Or to say it another way, I need to be able to reference the class properties/methods in the game factory, then I could instantiate both (grid, game) in the controller and pass the grid instance to the game instance.

Comment: I edited my answer with your code. I tried to make it the way you intend, but i'm not sure. And it is **untested**. How many `Grid` and `Game` instances will exist in your `myApp`? Returning a function from a angular `factory` is not the way its meant to be, but since in JavaScript functions are first class objects it will work. The name `factory` is a bit missleading.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but it is not ideal: http://jsfiddle.net/Frinkahedron/LJqz7/2/

I am now passing the parameters for the Grid into the Game function and creating the Game inside the Grid.

```
myApp.factory('game', ['grid', function (_grid_) {
    var grid = _grid_;

    //TODO: instead of passing the parameters for the grid
    //into the game, I would prefer to pass the grid "class"
    //But that doesn't seem possible since java script 
    //doesn't recognize the "class" properties until the 
    //object is instantiated
    function game(sizeX, sizeY, gridName){
        this.gameGrid = new grid(3, 3, "Test Grid");
        this.gridName = "Grid - " + this.gameGrid.name;
    };

    game.prototype.isWinner = function () {
        for(var i=0; i< this.gameGrid.cells.length;i++){
            //set to false if necessary
        }
        return true;
    };

    return game;
}]);
```

And I can now reference the properties of the Grid correctly.

```
function MyCtrl($scope, grid, game) {
    var aGame = new game(3, 3, "Test Grid");

    $scope.myGridName = aGame.gameGrid.name;
    $scope.myLength = aGame.gameGrid.cells.length;
    $scope.myGameName = aGame.gridName;
    $scope.myWinner = aGame.isWinner();
}
```

However, I would still like to be able to pass the grid "class" into the game factory.  But this doesn't work because grid.cells is undefined until the grid is instantiated.  Can this be overcome in Java Script/Angular?

```
function game(grid){
    this.gridName = "Grid - " + grid.name;
};

game.prototype.isWinner = function () {
    for(var i=0; i< grid.cells.length;i++)
        //set to false if necessary
    }
    return true;
};
```